# Estimate re-implementing ASP.NET MVC app using Rails

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, ruby, project-management

How it would be possible to approximately **estimate time of re-implementing the same application in Rails** while already having one implemented in ASP.NET MVC (reason - is another topic, please let's not touch it here).

I am looking for some kind of metrics mapping or something that could possibly provide a rough estimation of time required.

Some details about the current ASP.NET MVC2 (.NET 4) project:

> ## Project Metrics
>
> - Maintainability Index - 85.4 (out of 100)
> - Test coverage ~ 80%
> - Depth of Inheritance - 1.9
> - Class Coupling - 5.5
> - Lines of Code - 17859 (9804 excluding tests)
>
> ## Aprox. number of
>
> - views ~ 200
> - custom JavaScripts files ~ 20
> - cstom CSS files ~ 20
>
> ## 3rd parties
>
> - Payment processing
> - Gespatial (in MSSQL 2008)
> - Google Maps Geocoding
> - ABRXMLSearch (Australian ABN Lookup service)
> - AWS S3
>
> ## Deployments
>
> - staging
> - production
> - demo

What I would like to see is approximate number of man-hours required to implement the same system, by the same developers (gurus in .NET, but junior-middle level in Rails).

This project was implemented approximately within 2450 man-hrs.

**UPDATE (more about project)**: Cannot tell a lot about it (you know, all those NDAs), so I'll have to generalise. It is a B2B app that allows to interact between 2 parties (provider - consumer like system). Consumer can 'share' the stuff provider gives to him with other consumers (but the should not know about that). There are number of "legal" processes that need to be followed. There are number of many-to-many allocations with embedded search and different rules related to them when consumer is searching. Sorry for such a "general" explanation, but that's only how far I can go.

What would be a possible **formula to estimate** this number for a Rail project.

**UPDATE:** According to comments, other non-formal ways will be better than a mathematical estimation based on a formula (so removing the formula from question).

How would it be possible to make an estimation about re-implementing the project in Rails?

Thanks.

Comment: Rails is a different beast that shines brightest in a more Agile, less "math-encumbered" management process. It's hard to tell how you got to where you are, nor why you have 200 views (I've seen more in a basic blog app). Long story short - wrong question. You need to ask why you're asking about moving off MVC.

Comment: There are number of reasons. One is that it is hard to test properly. Second, it is harder to evolve the app. Thirdly, much less friction with Rails and more business value (so I would like to know whether the time spent moving to Rails is reasonable). Also - we want to be small - both code and the team and live happily.

Comment: I would never estimate things this way - it's weird to use such formulas (read "The Mythical Man Month (...)", "The Passionate Programmer"). Software development is more art than engineering - everything depends on "soft" things like motivation, etc.

Comment: @Damian OK. What about huge passion for Rails and pain with .NET? The formula is far from being good. Can you suggest something different?

Comment: Just let your team try it. Investigate Rails for a week and see whether you are able to develop rapidly so that it won't take too much time.

Comment: @Damian, yeah. Team is ready to Drive Technical Change. It would be good to set reasonable time constraints for ourselves. And that's the main purpose for this question.  Also, @Rob, I was wondering how many view there are in a pretty complex Blogging app. So I run `find . -type f | grep -i "as[cp]x$" | wc -l` on BlogEngine.NET. The result is 69. So the app is a bit more complex than a basic blog app.

Comment: @Dmytrii - MVC is hard to test? I've not found that at all, infact the opposite, its easy to test, and gives me great confidence.  I'm reading a heap of hate for MVC and a heap of love for Ruby, which is fine, but I'm concerned you might be jumping ship prematurely based on some of these comments.

Comment: I'm with Michael Shimmins. aspnetmvc takes a lot from Rails and AFAIK both are as easily testable and maintainable? Sorry to intrude but do simply not like MS/.NET/aspnetmvc? Coz if you do that's kool, no disrespect.

Comment: Additionally it seems that the management approach that you intend on will violate a lot that Rails (and indeed aspnetmvc) is about - numbers, metrics, pain?

Comment: @Michael, @cottsak, MVC is much easier to test than any other .NET framework. But not even comparably as easy as Rails. I might be jumping, but that's the purpose of the question to get the understanding of it.

Comment: being a conspiracy theorist, i suspect that the app is actually already in ror and someone has asked the question as to why mvc wasn't used. :) - i jest ...of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise against trying to calculate an estimate with a formula like the one that you are providing or any other formula for that matter!

Rather than plain guessing (and make it look like "accurate math") my recommendation would be to pick one small module and rewrite it in Ruby and see how the team does. Use past-performance (history) as you guidance rather than hope and hearsay.

Given that the system was written by "gurus in .NET, but junior-middle level in Rails" I could almost guarantee that it will take you longer (perhaps much longer) to rewrite it in Ruby.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would change this:

> k - correlation between development speed in .NET and Rails (~ 0.5)

To ~ this:

> k - correlation between development speed in .NET and Rails (~ 1.5)

Not because Asp.Net > Rails, but because team is not familiar with it. Seems more realistic to me.

I'm in kind a similar position as a developer - feeling quite comfortable on asp.net mvc and learning simultaneously rails. No way I could work faster on RoR at the moment...

Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's interesting to know. How long are you working with Rails? What is the experience you/team have with it?

Comment: @Dmytrii not much. playing around with rails for ~1/2 year (got 3,5 years programming experience in total, mostly on asp.net, working with asp.net mvc since it came out).

Comment: @Dmytrii btw, I hope You don't count on RoR as silver bullet or some kind of salvation. at least my opinion is that software development is more about individuals - it's consciousness and actual thinking what makes things work. the same with methodologies - switching from waterfall to agile does not automatically summon rainbows all around.

Comment: @Dmytrii and one more last thing - be sure You really want to rewrite that app. http://bit.ly/aJcI2u it's highly risky. You should do that only if You can see finishing it successfully and application You are about to rewrite is worth it (in fancy words - gives You competitive advantage).

Answer (score 0):

Reading code is harder than writing code. I suspect it will take longer than you think, and probably longer than the original implementation.

The correlation of development between Ruby and .NET (.5) is interesting.  Where did this come from?  I presume you're pretty familiar with Ruby given you think its twice as fast to develop in as .NET, and you've only put 80 hours down for learning Ruby.

I don't have a formula for this, because any formula you use will be inaccurate and a best guess.

I would rather estimate the project the same way you estimate normal projects.  Rather than trying to compare the original development time to come up with an answer, actually estimate how long it will take to implement the project in Ruby (forgetting that you've already done it).

Check out this article for more in-depth discussion about why re-writing from the ground up, even in the same language, is almost always a bad idea:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Comment: The correlation came out of the blue (Rails is 2x faster to develop than .NET). No real-world basis on that. That's why I need your help guys. The 80 hrs for learning is because there is already enough "working" knowledge to go on with Rails.  Good point about rewriting, but while we are small we would like to experiment and see what works best. It is not rewriting 10 years old software.

Comment: BTW, Rob Conery rewrote TekPub 4 times, so it sounds like a pretty large difference from what Spolsky describes and what we are talking about here.